Text/image pop-ups on hover not showing up as expected
I found many examples that show similar functionality, but when I try tailoring those examples to a specific format - things do not work as I need them to.
What I am trying to achieve:

Having a block with three text lines of text
One of the lines contains two special characters - hovering over A would show a pop-up window with text, hovering over B would display an image

text1
text2 A B
text3

The example I found used applied the CSS style to a hyper link object, so to make it look like a regular text I added the following style:
.popup a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

To make the pop-up text or the image invisible but show up on mouse hover, I use the following two CSS styles:
.popup a span {
    display: none;
}

.popup a:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;     << "absolute" is not working well
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #335500;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}

The HTML contains the following:
<div class="popup">
  <br>text1
  <br>text2
  <a href="emty">A<span>LineX<br>LineY<br>LineZ</span></a>
  <a href="emty">B<span><img src="image.png"></span></a>
  <br>text3
</div>

The Problems:

when I hover over A or B, the description or the image show up, respectively. However, instead of floating above the page layer, the description or the image show up in-line, distorting/moving the current page layout and shifting everything based on its size.
The description or the image box traverse the entire page despite their smaller sizes and the fact that they belong to 
Changing position attribute from relative to absolute seems to help, but when I have similar objects down the page - they do not show up (probably because they are too down the page)

The Goals:

Get pop-up windows of description and image when hoovering over A or B, respectively, similar to how the tooltip works.
Have the description or image show up at the top right corner relative to the A or B, respectively

Please point me to my mistakes - I am not sure if this is the correct implementation path, so if there is a better approach to achieve this (preferably with HTML and CSS only), I would greatly appreciate your example.

Try: position: block;

@JayCravens that did not seem to have any effect

absolute positions relative to the nearest positioned ancestor element.
Therefore, position: relative was given to .popup a {}.
To position the :hover element at the top right of the span element, set top: 0, left: 100%.


.popup a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; // Set position value
}

.popup a span {
  display: none;
}

.popup a:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; // Positions relative to the nearest positioned ancestor element. (.popup a)
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  color: #335500;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}




Thank you for your help - your answer solved my issue!
